# Filter json data using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, filtering

My json data looks like this,

```
{"Table" : [{"accid" : "13","accname" : "Default","accountType" : "Default",
"noOfEmployes" : "","phone" : "","revenue" : "","webSite" : ""},
{"accid" : "15","accname" : "karpagam","accountType" : "Customer",
"noOfEmployes" : "60","phone" : "9894606677","revenue" : "","webSite" : ""},
{"accid" : "14","accname" : "VLB","accountType" : "Customer",
"noOfEmployes" : "60","phone" : "9865636371","revenue" : "","webSite" : ""},
{"accid" : "12","accname" : "XIT","accountType" : "Customer",
  "noOfEmployes" : "20","phone" : "4347980","revenue" : "1000000",
     "webSite" : "xavyinfotech.com"}]}
```

Now I have a textbox `account name` where my user can enter an account name like `D,d,kar` any character and now I want to match that text to my `accname` keys of my json data. My filter may produce 'n' number of results.. Any suggestion to Filter json data using jquery?

**EDIT:**

Should I depend on other libraries like [jslinq](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/) to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for jQuery.

```
for (el in data.Table) {
  if (somecondition(el.accname) {
    dosomethingwith(el);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ignacio will this remove all other rows during filter?

Comment: No. It will merely iterate through the rows and allow you to process the ones you're interested in.

Comment: @Ignacio i think you misunderstood my question... I want to filter in my json object without iterating through it...

Comment: You cannot filter without iterating somehow. What you do with the positive elements is your choice, but I'd add them to the control. Or another array if whatever you're using needs one.